# Libgdx when using skin in a Label it does not show when the application is being run

Tags: java, libgdx, skin

I've recently trying to give a background to my labels in Libgdx because without a custom skin, you are left with a blank slate with just some white text.

Using a skin editor found [here](https://github.com/cobolfoo/gdx-skineditor), I was able to make a style of label to my liking which I would want to use in my project. However, with the use of these files to build my skin, nothing seems to happen.

With these files, I've tried using:

```
skin1 = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skins/uiskin.json"),
            new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("skins/uiskin.atlas")));
```

and using it in my table:

```
Table table = new Table(skin);
```

and in my labels:

```
Label label = new Label("Test", skin);
```

but all to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea why it still shows up as plain white text?
Thank you very much.

This is the uiskin.json file

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    green: { g: 1, a: 1 },
    light_grey: { r: 0.8, g: 0.8, b: 0.8, a: 1 },
    white: { r: 1, g: 1, b: 1, a: 1 },
    red: { r: 1, a: 1 },
    Yellow: { r: 1, g: 1, a: 1 },
    grey: { r: 0.7, g: 0.7, b: 0.7, a: 1 },
    black: { a: 1 }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
    font_p_oorich_20pt: { file: font_p_oorich_20pt.fnt },
    font_p_oorich_18pt: { file: font_p_oorich_18pt.fnt },
    default-font: { file: default.fnt }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
    dialogDim: {
        name: white,
        color: { a: 1, b: 0.2, g: 0.2, r: 0.2 }
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle: {
    default: { background: default-scroll, knobBefore: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: {
        font: default-font,
        fontColor: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        disabledFontColor: { a: 1, b: 0.8, g: 0.8, r: 0.8 },
        up: default-round,
        down: default-round-down
    },
    toggle: {
        font: default-font,
        fontColor: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        downFontColor: { a: 1, r: 1 },
        up: default-round,
        down: default-round-down,
        checked: default-round-down
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton$ImageButtonStyle: {
    default: { imageUp: paint_brush, up: default-round, down: default-round-down }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SplitPane$SplitPaneStyle: {
    default-vertical: { handle: default-splitpane-vertical },
    default-horizontal: { handle: default-splitpane }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Touchpad$TouchpadStyle: {
    default: { background: default-pane, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
    default: { up: default-round, down: default-round-down },
    toggle: { up: default-round, down: default-round-down, checked: default-round-down }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: {
        background: default-window,
        titleFont: default-font,
        titleFontColor: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 }
    },
    dialog: {
        background: default-window,
        titleFont: default-font,
        titleFontColor: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        stageBackground: dialogDim
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
    default: {
        font: default-font,
        fontColor: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        background: textfield,
        cursor: cursor,
        selection: selection
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle: {
    default: {
        background: default-rect,
        hScroll: default-scroll,
        hScrollKnob: default-round-large,
        vScroll: default-scroll,
        vScrollKnob: default-round-large
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    optional: {
        font: default-font,
        fontColor: { a: 1, b: 0.7, g: 0.7, r: 0.7 }
    },
    default: {
        font: default-font,
        fontColor: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 }
    },
    Styletest: {
        font: font_p_oorich_20pt,
        fontColor: { a: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        background: default-round-large
    },
    error: {
        font: default-font,
        fontColor: { a: 1, r: 1 }
    },
    title: {
        font: default-font,
        fontColor: { a: 1, b: 0.8, g: 0.8, r: 0.8 }
    },
    Mainlabel: {
        font: font_p_oorich_20pt,
        fontColor: { a: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        background: default-round-down
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle: {
    default: {
        font: default-font,
        fontColorSelected: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        fontColorUnselected: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        selection: selection
    },
    dimmed: {
        font: default-font,
        fontColorSelected: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        fontColorUnselected: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        selection: selection,
        background: dialogDim
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle: {
    default: {
        checkboxOn: check-on,
        checkboxOff: check-off,
        font: default-font,
        fontColor: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 }
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree$TreeStyle: {
    default: { plus: tree-plus, minus: tree-minus, selection: default-select-selection }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle: {
    default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
    default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
    default: {
        font: default-font,
        fontColor: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
        background: default-select,
        scrollStyle: default,
        listStyle: default
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you might have given the style a different name? Look in the json file if the style is called "default"  if not, it won't work unless you give the style name as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `Label` like you did:

```
Label label = new Label("Test", skin);
```

Takes the default `LabelStyle` from `skin`, i.e., the `LabelStyle` which name is "default". In your case that style is:

```
default: {
    font: default-font,
    fontColor: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 }
},
```

Which specifies the color white as the font color. If you want a different style you can either change the default color or specify a different `LabelStyle` for your label. E.g:

```
Label label = new Label("Test", skin, "title");
```

will create a `Label` with the style "title", i.e.:

```
title: {
    font: default-font,
    fontColor: { a: 1, b: 0.8, g: 0.8, r: 0.8 }
},
```